# Rails ActiveRecord override default find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building an API wrapper that will query objects from a third-party API and build them into objects to be used in my Rails environment.  To do that, I'm building a set of models that use ActiveRecord (for some of its functionality) but are not database backed.  I would like to be able to make a call like this:

```
obj = MyModel.find(1)
```

And have the code be something like this:

```
def MyModel.find id
  # check for object in cache
  # check for object in db
  # grab object from API
  # return object
end
```

Am I going to do something horribly wrong if I override the default find method?  Am I approaching this in totally the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using a database, then you do not need ActiveRecord.  The entire purpose of ActiveRecord is to give you a mapping to a relational database.

I think what you want is for a class to implement certain pieces of what `ActiveRecord` provides, and Rails 3 has made those pieces into classes that you can include into regular 'ol classes on an as-needed basis.  Look at this article for more details: http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0s-activemodel-how-to-give-ruby-classes-some-activerecord-magic-2937.html

For instance, if you only want validations on a class, you can use `include ActiveModel::Validations` and then you'll get all of the nice error handling and `.valid?` and `validates presence: true` kind of behavior you're used to.

I would also suggest the railscast by Ryan Bates:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model which goes into more detail.